# Phantom Bugs using Queue (STL Library), Windows/MingW/G++

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, queue

I'm having two unexpected problems using Queue from the STL Library:

1) I'm trying to clear a Queue (Queue does not have a function clear),
but the intuitive way is giving me a CORE DUMP:

```
//The queue is defined Globally but the problem happens even
//if i define it locally and pass it by reference.
queue<pair<int,int> > Q;

void yadayada ()
{
    //initialize Q
    while (!Q.empty())
        Q.pop();   //CORE DUMP, what the hell?
}
```

2) When i print the element(a pair) from the queue front it is
wrongly printed as (0,0). But when i use the element (returning
the second element of the pair) it is right!

```
int yadayada2(...) 
{
//code...code...code

//the element in front is (4,20)
front = Q.front(); Q.pop();

cout << "(" << front.first << "," << front.second << ")" << endl;
//prints: (0,0) 
//what the hell?

//correctly returns 20
return front.second;
}

int main()
{
//code...code...code 

//prints 20!
cout << yadayada2 << endl;
}
```

I though: "Maybe the pop invalidates the element (does not make sense but...)
so i moved the Q.pop(); to just before the return. But the same thing still happens...

Comment: Is `front` a reference or a value type?

Comment: Can you provide your *actual* code?

Comment: Oli Charlesworth : I fixed it, thanks and sorry to take your time.

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to clear a queue is:

```
Q = queue< pair< int, int > >(); // assign value of an empty temporary
```

As for the `front` bug, I have to agree with Oli and suspect that there is an invalid reference.

Comment: You could point out that it also relinquishes any surplus allocated capacity. This makes it better in most situations

Answer (score 2):

On the WTF:

- either your code is subtle more wrong in real life (todo with replacing int with something else, such as involving auto_ptr, classes without proper copy/assignment semantics etc?)
- OR: your mingw setup is borked.

I just cmpiled both  snippets using g++ on linux AND i586-mingw32msvc-g++ AND ran it under wine AND valgrind... no problems :)

Comment: To take a real long shot: there might be an operator overload or implicit conversion gone wrong. Especially the operator << of int could be borken for some reason